# Screen rotation changes settings

Tags: android, rotation

In my Android app I have 2 layouts, one for portrait and one for landscape.

In both layouts I have a TextView that the user can change by clicking on, by default it reads 'ON'
If the user presses it then it changes to 'OFF' All well and good.

However if it's set to OFF and the screen is rotated the text view resets to ON. How can I stop this from happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that this question is asked every single day, the answer is to look into configChanges with regards to AndroidManifest.xml It allows you to override the default behaviour when the devices config changes, the default behaviour for a change of orientation is that the app restarts.

A common line to add into the AndroidManifest is used here:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
            class=".MyActivity" 
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Then if you want to perform any specific action on the orientation change you need to override the Activity method onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: If the change in orientation resets the app then why is it just this one thing that is effected? I have 5 EditText boxes with data in, plus a spinner and they all retain their state. The only thing that is reset is the TextView. I have not used any onConfigurationChanged() commands anywhere so I cant be overriding them.
Can you please explain why this may be happening? Or if these questions are being asked every day please can you supply a link to one.
Cheers.

Comment: sure, if that is the case then can you paste the TextView sections of the two layouts into here, maybe it isn't to do with the app restart. Also in the mean time it would be interesting if you could try adding that line into your activity just to be certain.